# Syntax error in this method button C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access, syntax-error

I need your help, I can't find the error, it's an emergency, here is my method
and a image of the error the error say "syntax error INSERT INTO statement" here is an image, how can I fix it, no matter how its the structure

http://img718.imageshack.us/img718/8864/erroruh.jpg[image]

```
private void btnCronograma_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string connstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\amaury\\Documents\\TEC\\Septimo Semestre\\Administracion de proyectos de ingenieria de softwaere\\nuevo4\\nuevo\\Office\\Office\\Policias.accdb";
  using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
   {
    conn.Open();

    string sql = "INSERT INTO IndicadorProyecto (idProyecto, idMes, meta, real) VALUES(@idProyecto , @idMes , @meta, @real)";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView8.Rows)
  {
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo3 = row.Cells["idProyecto"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell combo4 = row.Cells["idMes"] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;

    if (combo3 == null || combo4 == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se pudo convertir");
        continue;
    }

  int idProyecto = int.Parse(combo3.Value.ToString());
  int idMes = int.Parse(combo4.Value.ToString());
  int meta = int.Parse(row.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
  int real = int.Parse(row.Cells[4].Value.ToString());  

  cmd.Parameters.Clear();
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idProyecto", idProyecto);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idMes", idMes);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meta", meta);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@real", real);


  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
}
```

Comment: I am fairly sure the values should read `VALUES (?,?,?,?)`

Comment: how can you explain further? you mean change the part of values for VALUES (?,?,?,?)

Comment: I think remou means Access does not support named parameters (like @meta)

Comment: Isn't it ODBC that doesn't support named parameters?

Comment: @David-W-Fenton OLEDB, used above, does not support named parameters with MS Access (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e5545e1.aspx), but does, as far as I can see, with SQL Server (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(VS.71).aspx), so to say "Access does not support named parameters" may not be the full story, but seems reasonable enough for a comment on this post.

Comment: But it's not Access that's causing the problem -- it's the database interface layer you're using, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear: Error in INSERT INTO statement.

I don't seen any SQL syntax problem so I'll guess it is about a reserve word, try escaping them with `[]` :

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO IndicadorProyecto (idProyecto, idMes, [meta], [real]) 
             VALUES(@idProyecto , @idMes , @meta, @real)";
```

Combined with Remou's observation of named parameters it becomes:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO IndicadorProyecto (idProyecto, idMes, [meta], [real]) 
             VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

And you have to be very careful about adding the parameters in the right order.

Comment: thank you very much it works!!, I still have a doubt how can I control exception? it display a message that says: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Better make that a new question. And try to post only the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using OLEDB provider, so probably you will have to used the "?" symbol for the parameters. You can try the following query:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO IndicadorProyecto (idProyecto, idMes, [meta], [real]) 
         VALUES(?, ? , ?, ?)";
```